# Using Distinct Count within/with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, case

I have  the below code which returns the results as seen below (please note order method is only used so that I can sort the data)

```
   Week_Variance_Range  Returns_Due ORDERMETHOD
   Thisweek              11            05
   -1                    11            02
   -2                    12            03
   -3                    5             04
```

Now this brings through all the data and I've just discovered that there are duplicated return ids (`RtnId`) yet my analysis requires distinct values.

So for `This week` lets say there have been 11 Returns. 2 may have come from the same return Id and as a result this week's figure should be 10 rather than 11.

Please see by code below:

```
SELECT        
    Week_Variance_Range, 
    COUNT(*) AS Returns_Due, 
    CASE 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = 'Created This Week ' THEN '01' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-1' THEN '02' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-2' THEN'03' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-3' THEN '04' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-4' THEN '05' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-5' THEN '06' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-9 to - 6    ' THEN '07' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-19 to - 10  ' THEN '08' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-39 to - 20  ' THEN '09' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-59 to - 40  ' THEN '10' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-79 to - 60  ' THEN '11' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-99 to - 80  ' THEN '12' 
       WHEN t.Week_Variance_Range = '-500 to - 100 ' THEN '13' 
    END AS ORDERMETHOD
FROM (
    SELECT        
       CASE
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 500 AND - 100 THEN '-500 to - 100 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 99 AND - 80 THEN '-99 to - 80 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 79 AND - 60 THEN '-79 to - 60 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 59 AND - 40 THEN '-59 to - 40 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 39 AND - 20 THEN '-39 to - 20 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 19 AND - 10 THEN '-19 to - 10 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 BETWEEN - 9 AND - 6 THEN '-9 to - 6 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 = - 5 THEN '-5 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 = - 4 THEN '-4 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 = - 3 THEN '-3 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 = - 2 THEN '-2 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 = - 1 THEN '-1 ' 
          WHEN abs(DATEDIFF(WEEK, RtnDt, GETDATE())) * - 1 = 0 THEN 'Created This Week ' 
       END AS Week_Variance_Range
    FROM dbo.vw_AN_Admin_VendorReturns
    WHERE (Complete <> 'X')
) AS t
GROUP BY Week_Variance_Range
ORDER BY ORDERMETHOD
```

Comment: Consider putting your case text in a table and going to it - a column for text.  A  table would need to join 6,7,8,9 all to the same caseText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `RtnId` to the select statement in the derived table and use `count(distinct rtnid)` in the outer query.

```
SELECT        
    Week_Variance_Range, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT RtnId) AS Returns_Due, 
    /* long case expression */
FROM (
    SELECT RtnId,      
        /* long case expression */
    FROM dbo.vw_AN_Admin_VendorReturns
    WHERE (Complete <> 'X')
) AS t
GROUP BY Week_Variance_Range
ORDER BY ORDERMETHOD
```